# Iterating through vectors

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, text-files

I'm trying to add string values from a text file to a vector. While doing that, I'm also checking the strings for the number of characters then when reach the word with the desired number of characters, I then add that string into the vector.

But when I'm debugging my program, I keep seeing out of bounds exception and it prints out strings higher than the desired number of characters.

```
vector<string> words;
vector<string> chosenWords;
ifstream in("WordDatabase.txt");

while(in) {
  string word;
  in >> word;
  cout << word << endl;
  //push in selected words based on num of chars
  words.push_back(word);
}

for(vector<string>::iterator itr=words.begin(); itr!=words.end();++itr)
{
    if((*itr).length() >= 2 || (*itr).length() <= 7)
    {
        cout << (*itr) << endl;
        chosenWords.push_back(*itr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line does the out-of-bounds error correspond to?

Comment: Lengths that are 2+ or 7- that sounds like a weird condition. Are sure sure you didn't mean && ?

Comment: Dammit. U solved it in 2 mins while i took 2-3hours thinking abt it. Thanks BORG!

Comment: @KerrekSB huh what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lengths that are 2+ or 7- that sounds like a weird condition. Most likely your conditional should be:

```
if((*itr).length() >= 2 && (*itr).length() <= 7)
```

As a side note, you're better off reading words like this:

```
string word;
while(in >> word) {
  cout << word << endl;
  //push in selected words based on num of chars
  words.push_back(word);
}
```

Comment: What's the difference? Sorry if i sound noobish coz i only started c++ 2-3 weeks ago.

Comment: I believe that this version covers edge cases that your version doesn't. I'd have to dig to find the specific answer to this but if you roam SO enough you'll find that this is the canonical way of doing things.

Comment: @JoelSeah: Your `while (in)` loop is wrong for the same reason `while (!in.eof())` is wrong. See: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/445976)